# How to display image and text in a tableviewcell

Tags: iphone, image, text, uitableview

I have strings like this -

> abcdefgh http://abc.abc.jpg adffggjk

The number of images is variable.
How can I display the image and text in a correct sequence in a tabview cell?

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by customizing TableViewCell.

Design a data structure in that holds all your data(like a class with String array and image path array). Pass that to your custom cell and there add Lables and ImageView and subview for each string and Image in order you want.

If you have too much of data than you can adjust height of cell in heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

if you have too much of data then designing a UIScrollview and adding them in a Other ScrollView would be better idea.

Hope this is helpful...

Post if you need more help....

Comment: How to set the position of the image?

Comment: set frame property of UIImageView and add it as a subview in contentView of Cell